# Perform Python Entity Resolution on rows in same column

Tags: python, function, fuzzywuzzy

I have a data as displayed in the picture which is for different entities (name of companies or addresses).
I have an issue where the same entity is included in many different variations in the same column of data (as you can see with the first two rows).

I have researched a lot about the use of fuzzywuzzy and Python Record Linkage toolkit but all of these are for use across different dataframes.

How can I perform this same activity using python and specifically apply it on records in the same column (not different dataframes) please? Ideally the result would be a standardised entity

I need a function to perform this on a column - sorry I am new to functions and any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL34O.png]

Comment: Maybe this article can help you? http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/fuzzing-matching-in-pandas-with-fuzzywuzzy/ Using pandas you could clean your dataset by subsetting on every unique company name and then correcting the name for all of them.

Comment: thanks very much Nehalem. this would be very helpful - would you please be able to help me apply this in code? I am new to using functions I imagine some sort of itertool process to search each row is required?

Comment: The article uses pandas, a popular Python library for panel data in Python. On large datasets it is vastly faster than using Python functions. First of all, you need to open you dataset in pandas and familiarise yourself with subsetting. Start here (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html#min-tut-02-read-write) and here (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#min-tut-03-subset) and update your question with your progress. It also helps to include a small dataset that others can use to test the code.

Comment: Hi Nehalem, I have added a picture of the data table for you to see. Please can you share how you would approach this? I am familiar with Pandas but this is beyond me